# How can I delete one part of the string without deleting the same set of characters in another place?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to clean up a string (URL). I need that every time it contains `ipfs://ipfs/` to replace it by a single `ipfs/`.
The full string is `ipfs://ipfs/QmR6xjBCn`
but it should be  `ipfs://QmR6xjBCn`
In some cases I get string that are already clean, in other cases I dont'.

Comment: Just use `string.replace()`

Comment: It's not even a complex pattern, just a fixed string. Replace `ipfs://ipfs` with `ipfs://`

Comment: You cannot delete some chars of a string in-place because js strings are immutable, but you can create a new string with those chars replaced by whatever you want, using the `String.prototype.replace` method

Comment: Thank you. But in some cases it has that pattern `ipfs://ipfs` and in some cases it doesn't and I get it like i need it `ipfs://` ... How can I detect that, before I create a new string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the replace() function. If the text is not in the string then it won't replace anything. So it only works when the double ipfs is there.

```js
let str;
// example one
str = "ipfs://ipfs/QmR6xjBCn";
str = str.replace("ipfs://ipfs/","ipfs://");
console.log(str);

// example two, same code different url
str = "ipfs://SomethingRandom";
str = str.replace("ipfs://ipfs/","ipfs://");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used include to detect if the string contained `ipfs://ipfs` and then replaced it for what I needed: `ipfs://`

```
if (fixedURL.includes('ipfs://ipfs')) {
  fixedURL2 = fixedURL.replace('ipfs://ipfs','ipfs://')

  obj.imageUrl = fixedURL2;
} else {

  obj.imageUrl = fixedURL;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged

Comment: Thanks. added comment/description